# How to get max count for particular product and group by custom id from sql database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mysqli, sqlite

I have following database and needs to get a max count for a particular product with the group by customer id from SQL database.

[image]

I tried with SQL subquery, but not able to get solved. Please help me to solve this problem.

I need output as like following if product name is `bajari`,

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Yes I have updated my question

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query

```
select customer_id, product_name, count(product_name) as mostcount from `products`  where product_name='bajari' group by customer_id having count(product_name) =
( select max(mostcount) as highest_total
    from (
         select customer_id
              , count(product_name) as mostcount
           from `products` where product_name='bajari'
         group
             by customer_id
         ) as t
);
```

For step by step solution, please check the same solution to [here](https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Finding-the-highest-COUNT-in-a-GROUP-BY-query).

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

Standard *SQL* uses`GROUP BY` clasue with `subquery` aggregation:

```
select customer_id, Product_name, count(*) mostcount
from table t
group by customer_id, Product_name
having count(*) = (select max(counts) 
                   from (select customer_id, count(*) counts
                         from table t
                         group by customer_id, Product_name)
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% find_array_max = [] %>
<% count = 0%>
<%@customers.each do |customer|%>
  <%  count = @products.where(product_name: 'bajari', customer_id: customer.id).sum(:weight)%>
  <% find_array_max.push(count) %>
<% end -%>
  <%= find_array_max.max%>.kg
  <%= find_array_max.min%>.kg
```